# How would I filter a column for all dates within 1 week from today in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula

I am trying to filter all dates in a column within 1 week/7 days in the future from today using the same autofilter method in VBA shown below. My column of interest this time is Field:=53

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table22").Range.AutoFilter Field:=129, Criteria1:= _
    "UPCOMING"
```

I'm wondering if this is possible to do, and if so how?

Comment: Will tomorrow be today tomorrow?

Comment: @SolarMike yes, by today I dont mean a stagnant date. today is whatever day it is when the code is run. Im sorry I should have clarified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From today till this day next week:

```vb
.AutoFilter Field:=53, Criteria1:=">=" & Date, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Date + 7
```

You can also use special values to quickly set the filter to "this week" or "next week". See [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldynamicfiltercriteria) all possible special values.

```vb
'This Week
.AutoFilter Field:=53, Criteria1:=xlFilterThisWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

'Next Week
.AutoFilter Field:=53, Criteria1:=xlFilterNextWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the filter like this:

```
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table22").Range.AutoFilter 129, ">=" & CLng(Date), xlAnd, "<=" & CLng(DateAdd("d", 7, Date))
```

To filter for dates it is necessary to convert them to a long value, otherwise the filter won't work.

Comment: I haven't run into an issue filtering with dates without converting them. What kind of situations cause that issue for you?

Comment: If I take your solution (the first one)  and run it, the whole list is filtered out - no rows are visible. I know that from other projects I have been working on. Maybe it is due to a German system/German date settings? xlFilterNextWeek works :-)